# Solving the linear combination of sinusoidal functions

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, optimization

Is there a closed form solution for the following linear combination.
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \alpha_n\cos(\beta_n x+\gamma_n)=0,
\end{align}
where $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$ and $\gamma_n$ are known real non-zero numbers.

Comment: There is no $n$ inside the sum. Please fix this.

Comment: Thank you Stefan.

Comment: What is the source of this Problem and what did you try?

Comment: Solving this problem helps to solve an optimization problem. It seemed to be an obvious problem, but I couldn't find anything to solve it.

Comment: What kind of numbers are $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$, $\gamma_n$: integers, rationals, reals, complex?

Comment: Are real numbers